# Is there a way to open Minecraft without using the launcher at all?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Is there a way to open Minecraft without using the launcher? My launcher is taking a long time to open and I do not want to wait so long before I can actually play the game.

Comment: Note the launcher is responsible for logging you into your account. You won't be able to log into any servers if you skip that step.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but [MultiMC](https://multimc.org/) is an open-source alternative to the normal Minecraft launcher. I've been using it for about a year and it works very nicely.

MultiMC has many additional config options & features over the normal Minecraft launcher, most notably the ability to run multiple versions of Minecraft with seperate .minecraft instances.

Comment: This says "acquisition of profile failed" when I enter my Mojang username and password. Is it because it's trying to log me in, but is failing because I have no Microsoft account? If so, then this answer does not work to avoid having to get a Microsoft account. I want to play Minecraft, a single player game I paid for, but I don't want a Microsoft account, which was not required when I bought it.

Comment: @felwithe Avoiding the use of a Microsoft account was not the question and is not possible. Things change. If you don't migrate to a Microsoft account now, you will lose your license.