# Can Minecraft: Java Edition be opened using the Terminal on MacOS?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, minecraft-launcher

I play *Minecraft* Java Edition, but the launcher takes too long to load.

Is it possible to use a command on my macOS's Terminal to manually launch *Minecraft*?

Comment: Hi, ThatBananaNinja, what terminal?

Comment: The terminal is another term for the command line. Why has this been downvoted? This is a really good idea.

Comment: I am currently working a solution to this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to open Minecraft without using the launcher at all?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370705/is-there-a-way-to-open-minecraft-without-using-the-launcher-at-all)

Comment: That still requires the launcher, and the other answer does not show how exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a tool](https://gitlab.com/TheKodeToad/KwikLaunch) (that I created) for this purpose. It supports Mojang and Microsoft accounts.

By default, Minecraft runs in a sort of "portaloo" mode, where the game files (saves, packs etc...) are stored separately. To change this, simple edit the `directory` property in `config.yaml`.

### Here are the instructions:

First, install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Next, [download this repository](https://gitlab.com/TheKodeToad/KwikLaunch/-/archive/main/KwikLaunch-main.zip), and unzip it.

In the folder, run:

```
npm i
node index.js --init
```

This will create config.yaml:

```
# The folder to run Minecraft in.
directory: ./minecraft

# The version of Minecraft to run.
version: 1.17.1

# Optional: JVM Arguments.
jvmArgs:
- argument
- another argument
- I have a lot of arguments.

# Optional: Memory settings
memory:
  min: 1G
  max: 2G

# Optional: Java Path.
javaPath: /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Run the game:

```
node index.js
```

On first run, this will allow you to log in.

To force a log in (if you have multiple accounts):

```
node index.js --login
```

If the repository is suddenly deleted, that will probably be if I accidentally leak information.